# SQL Query execution plan changes with where clause values

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a query written that looks at data points in a large table (200M+ rows) based on date ranges. The query is pretty straightforward, uses a CTE and then aggregates from the CTE:

```
;WITH LMP
AS (
    SELECT CAISO.NODE AS NODE
        ,'CAISO' AS ISO
        ,[State]
        ,[County]
        ,(LMP) LMP
        ,(MCC) MCC
        ,(MCL) MCL
        ,(MCC_Perc_LMP) MCC_Perc_LMP
        ,(MCL_Perc_LMP) MCL_Perc_LMP
    FROM CAISO
    INNER JOIN CAISO_NODES ON CAISO.NODE = CAISO_NODES.NODE
    LEFT JOIN [Lookup:State] ON [Lookup:State].StateID = CAISO_NODES.StateID
    LEFT JOIN [Lookup:County] ON [Lookup:County].CountyID = CAISO_NODES.CountyID
    WHERE INTERVAL BETWEEN '2/18/2017'
            AND '3/3/2017'
    )
SELECT NODE
    ,ISO
    ,[State]
    ,[County]
    ,AVG(LMP) AvgLMP
    ,MAX(LMP) MaxLMP
    ,MIN(LMP) MinLMP
    ,AVG(MCC) AvgMCC
    ,MAX(MCC) MaxMCC
    ,MIN(MCC) MinMCC
    ,AVG(MCL) AvgMCL
    ,MAX(MCL) MaxMCL
    ,MIN(MCL) MinMCL
    ,AVG(MCC_Perc_LMP) Avg_MCC_Perc_LMP
    ,AVG(MCL_Perc_LMP) Avg_MCL_Perc_LMP
FROM LMP
GROUP BY NODE
    ,ISO
    ,[State]
    ,County
```

This table is indexed on the INTERVAL column

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX__CAISO__INTERVALSTARTTIME_GMT__NODE_PRICES] ON [dbo].[CAISO] ([INTERVAL] ASC) INCLUDE (
    [NODE]
    ,[LMP]
    ,[MCC]
    ,[MCE]
    ,[MCL]
    )
    WITH (
            PAD_INDEX = OFF
            ,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
            ,SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
            ,DROP_EXISTING = OFF
            ,ONLINE = OFF
            ,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
            ,ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
            ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now this query runs perfectly fine for our purposes, about 6-10 seconds for execution. However, if I change those dates from '2/18/2017' and '3/3/2017' to '4/18/2017' and '5/3/2017', the query takes well over a minute to execute.

What's most puzzling is the execution plan changes.

With the original query:
[image: Good Execution]

With the changed dates:
[image: Bad Execution]

I just can't figure out why the execution plan is changing - for the worse - when we query more recent data. Is there an index population I need to perform? A step I'm missing? You can see on the far right that both queries are hitting my index. Any tips? suggestions?

(Also, I don't love that LEFT JOIN but it's necessary to return STATE and COUNTY for the result set even if it's a NULL)

(Also Also I'm using the CTE rather than just a straight SELECT-WHERE-GROUP query because I'm also unioning in other data into the CTE before aggregating in other applications. I'm mostly concerned about this one table's execution.)

Comment: Update statistics on the table. Or alternatively use variables or parameters and an `optimize for` hint with a period covered by the statistics.

Comment: db showstatistics on that table with index used in 'Internal' column... Based on the data you might require to do update statistics on that index

Comment: If your stats are up to date and you still cant get the parallel plan give this article a read. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx

Comment: Brilliant, I'm updating statistics as we speak. I appreciate all the input.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert the stats don't look up to date. From the Line thickness looks like it estimates one row from the seek on the index in the top right and that propagates through the plan. Hence nested loops.

Comment: It was absolutely the statistics. I ran updates on all of my statistics and the execution plans match now and the query runs in the expected amount of time. Thank you all so much.

Comment: SO won't let me mark my own answer, so thank you 3 fine commenters for helping me with this issue.